# Ableton 10 : automate tempo without warping midi clip (like no-warp on audio)

Tags: midi, ableton-live, tempo

I use ableton live 10 and I like to record things without metronome, then automate the master tempo accordingly.

This works really good with audio tracks (eg. a guitar or vocals) provided I **de-activate the warp** button on the audio clip.

Now I'd like to **do the same with MIDI** (record without metronome then adjust tempo).
I found 3 solutions so far :

- freezing the track to audio, which is not what I want
- setting tempo automation *before* recording and recording with a metronome, which does not allow me to record freely
- the best solution so far : use midi "warp" markers or quantization to have the midi straight on tempo THEN reautomate the tempo (based on a duplicate track frozen to audio, to have the right changes). This is hard work and really not precise...

Does anybody knows a trick, a workaround for this specific situation ?

Maybe Ableton live 11 has enabled proper MIDI warping ? I would have seen it in my google researches I guess...

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what isn’t working? It is not clear from your post

Comment: I try to find a way to record midi freely, then to adjust the tempo automation so that the beats fall right

Comment: I've tried to do this in version 9, and couldn't find any sensible way to make the timeline match freely recorded MIDI. In the end, I just completely disregarded Ableton's bars/beats grid and manually played a tambourine track to serve as a metronome for further overdubs. If you'd like to use MIDI quantizing for _some_ parts, sorry, can't do. If you want to play without the computerized MIDI handicap crutches, you'll actually have to be able to play. ;)